# How to display a "zoom-able" SVG file in Android?

Tags: android, svg

My question is somewhat based off of this question. [Displaying SVG files in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535780/displaying-svg-files-in-android)

I have decided to display an SVG in my app, and I do so using the svg-android library. My problem is now how to add pinch to zoom functionality. Maybe this library is outdated and someone knows of another to accomplish this task. From what I see in the javadocs of svg-android, there doesn't seem to be any easy way to add pinch to zoom.

Answer (score 0):

That's not something that needs to necessarily be part of the SVG library.  You just need to implement `onTouchEvent()` in your view and use a `ScaleGestureListener` etc to keep track of your scales and pans.

http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html

Comment: Would you think it's possible to just load it in a webview?