# Is there any way to implement an android application to display India map SVG file and make some interaction with svg file?

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, svg.js, androidsvg

Is there any way to implement an android application to display India map SVG file and make some interaction with svg file like selecting states of india on click. Zooming in , zooming out. Consider india as a single svg file having all states information/graphic?

I am able to add svg file in the application as a vector image into an image view and its static not interactive

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't interact with svg file . To interect with it, you have to use Google map by integrating it with your android project. SDK is available for that.

But yes, you can use zoom-in, zoom-out functionalities for svg file , for that you can get a reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22890515/6880611) post.

Comment: Are there any such libraries available?

Comment: libraries for what ? @PrashanthYN

Comment: Library for selection or interaction of components inside SVG image file.like this https://github.com/jiahuanyu/SVGMapView

Comment: @PrashanthYN library, you have mentioned (Which is also no longer supported) is just for display ,zoom  in and zoom out . To interact with it (Like get lat,long etc.. ) . you have to integrate google map sdk only .

Comment: @PrashanthYN if you find this answer usefull please mark it as accepted .so that others can also get benefits .

Comment: Sure. Thank you.

Comment: do you have any idea about using android WebView to achieve this?

Comment: You can use Webview and d3js library to display svg and interact with it.

Comment: @R.Kut acknowledged